# How to pass state parameter in Slack oauth flow

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, slack-api

I am having hard time for days with this one.
How can I add the state paramater to the slack aouth flow?

My code below works fine with all parts except the state value. it attempts to add a dummy state value to the URL and it doesn't work, I understand that it has to be generated randomly, but i am more focused on how to even add it to the url for this stage.

any help would be appreciated.

```
function getSlackAccessToken(code) {
  var clientId = 'XXXXXX';
  var clientSecret = 'XXXXXX';
  var redirectUri = 'XXXXXX';

  var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': {
      'client_id': clientId,
      'client_secret': clientSecret,
      'code': code,
      'redirect_uri': redirectUri
    }
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://slack.com/api/oauth.v2.access', options);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  return data;
}

function getSlackOAuthUrl() {
  var clientId = 'XXXXXX';
  var redirectUri = 'XXXXXX';
  var state = 'XHSH980'; // Your state parameter value

  // Build the authorization URL with the state parameter
  var authUrl = 'https://slack.com/oauth/v2/authorize' +
    '?client_id=' + clientId +
    '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(redirectUri) +
    '&state=' + state + // Add the state parameter
    '&scope=incoming-webhook';

  return authUrl;
}


function doGet(e) {
  var code = e.parameter.code;
  if (!code) { 
    var url = getSlackOAuthUrl();
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(url); 
  }
  try {
    var data = getSlackAccessToken(code);

    if (data.ok) {
      if(data.incoming_webhook){
        return ContentService.createTextOutput("The app was connected successfully");

  
      } else {
        // handle error, the incoming_webhook is not present in the returned data
        return ContentService.createTextOutput("Incoming webhook not present in the returned data.");
      }
    } else {
      // handle error, the data object contains error message
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("Error: " + data.error);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // handle error
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Error: " + error);
  }}
```

Comment: Try to use this 
`let state = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);` once.

Comment: @DavidTeo Thanks, I did, I still don't get the state parameter in the URL at all.

Comment: How about to add `const state = e.parameter.state`?

Comment: @DavidTeo Thanks , i am afraid that still don't see any state value in the URL :(((

Comment: So in this example, `authUrl` that returns from `getSlackOAuthUrl()` isn't including the `state` argument you've directly added using string concatenation? That would be pretty unusual. The sequence here is that you attach a `state` to the authorization URL as you're doing here. You receive the `state` again when the installing user arrives at the URL you set your `redirectUri` value to. It's up to you then to validate the `state` matches what you originally set. `state` is not used or returned for the access token step you're performing in `getSlackAccessToken()`.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel: https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2